# php mail function is not working even its showing true condition part

Tags: php

my php mail() function is not working even its right here it is

```
            $to = $email_id;
            $sub = "FORGOT PASSWORD";
            $msg = $password;


            $headers =  'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; 
            $headers .= 'From: Your name <example@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"; 

           $mail= mail($to,$sub,$msg,$headers);


            if($mail) 
            { 
               ?>
               <script>alert('Your password has been successfully sent to you');</script>
               <?

            }
            else
            {
              ?>
                <script>alert('Please try again later');</script>      
              <?
            }
```

its alert if part i.e. **Your password has been successfully sent to you** but i did not received any email please help me and i am not using any HTML css in sending this mail.

Comment: Your mail is jenky. `mail($to, $sub, $msg, $headers);`

Comment: var_dump your variable

Comment: @Rasclatt if i write in this way mail($to, $sub, $msg, $headers); then its showing please try again later.

Comment: @abhiAhere var_dump($mail); showing bool(true)

Comment: For god's sake cant you use <?php tag instead of `<?` ?  Is that difficult ?

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com haha short_open_tag in ON dear thats why.

Comment: But you never know your server wherer you will deploy will have it ON or not !! What if it doesnt allow to change the setting ? And you still didnt answer, Why do you `Live` short tags ?

Comment: I said var_dump($to,$sub,$headers,$msg); Are you getting values

Comment: Make sure the you are using from email in this format user@yourdomainname.com

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 i am trying on sub domain so i have to write sub domain address or domain address ?

Comment: Write domain address

Comment: @abhiAhere Thank you so much you are 100 % correct i tried with domain name and its worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your headers are incorrect use your headers in this way it will resolved your problem getting true part is not a big deal

```
$headers =  'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; 
            $headers .= 'From: Your name <example@you_domain_name.com>' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

if not resolved give me the result you get using `var_dump($mail); showing bool(true)`

Comment: 100% correct i was using @gmail.com so it was not working thank you Mr. Ravi.......

Answer (score 1):

use

```
$mail= mail($to, $sub, $msg, $headers);
```

You dont need string as all variables are Already string.

Comment: if i write in this way mail($to, $sub, $msg, $headers); then its showing please try again later

Comment: maybe mailing is not allowed , or not set for your localhost !!!!!!  You need to do setting to make localhost send email.

Answer (score 0):

no need to use "" in the mail function if you are storing it in a variable allready. 
second thing check what you are getting in `$email_id;` variable is it the correct email address you are trying to send email .
 simply use like this

```
  <?php
    $to = $email_id;
    $sub = "FORGOT PASSWORD";
    $msg = $password;
    $headers = "From: webmaster@example.com" . "\r\n" .
    "CC: somebodyelse@example.com";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $mail=mail($to,$sub,$msg ,$headers);

if($mail) 
 { 
 ?>
    <script>alert('Your password has been successfully sent to you');</script>
 <?

}


 else
 {
 ?>
  <script>alert('Please try again later');</script>      
 <?
 }
?>
```

Update

also please check your spam folder. as if you are using other domain as `from email` these emails may go to the spam folder . or you can use these headers

```
 $headers = "From: webmaster@example.com" . "\r\n" .
        "CC: somebodyelse@yourdimain.com";  // enter your domain email
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

Comment: if i write in this way mail($to, $sub, $msg, $headers); then its showing please try again later

Comment: working fine on my pc . . please check with a static email address in `$to="email@email.com"`

Comment: also please check your spam folder . because image from the other domain may go in the spam folder

Comment: maybe mailing is not allowed , or not set for your localhost !!!!!! You need to do setting to make localhost send email

Comment: $mail= mail("myemail@gmail.com", "FORGOT PASSWORD", "hello", $headers); is it correct because its showing please try again later :-(

Comment: if mailing is not working then follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889439/how-to-check-if-php-mail-is-enabled

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com i am trying on server

Comment: Budddddy , email setting is NOT proper. Contact your host.

Comment: IF `$mail= mail("myemail@gmail.com", "FORGOT PASSWORD", "hello", $headers);` , here you Hard code email id and All , still shows ERROR , ask host provider why email is not working. Getting ??

Comment: with static email if not working then you should check you php info and contact with your host provider . as for me its working on both localhost and server.

Comment: @ris yes i checked spam folder did not find any mail

Comment: then contact with the host provider to check the mail function . or if you have ssh access you can do it from here.

Answer (score 0):

Use this mail($to, $sub, $msg, $headers),

If it returns true, then **check your spam folder**.

Answer (score 0):

```
Write your domain name   
$headers .= 'From: Your name <example@yorudomainname>' . "\r\n";

example <example@stackoverflow.com/>
```

Comment: Explanation is simple Write your domain name in header,$headers .= 'From: Your name <example@yorudomainname>' . "\r\n";