# Send email with PHP Contact Form

Tags: contact-form

i want to use this contact form in my website. but it got error when i click send. i really dont know how to solve it but with my litlle knowledge its jquery problem that can passed so it got error. its very important  for me to solve it . this codes that you will need . thank you for helping me and sorry for my bad english

php code :

```
//Retrieve form data. 
//GET - user submitted data using AJAX
//POST - in case user does not support javascript, we'll use POST instead
$name = ($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : $_POST['name'];
$email = ($_GET['email']) ?$_GET['email'] : $_POST['email'];
$message = ($_GET['message']) ?$_GET['message'] : $_POST['message'];

//flag to indicate which method it uses. If POST set it to 1
if ($_POST) $post=1;

//Simple server side validation for POST data, of course, you should validate the email
if (!$name) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your name.';
if (!$email) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your email.'; 
if (!$message) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your message.'; 

//If the errors array is empty, send the mail
if (!$errors) {

// ====== Your mail here  ====== //
$to = 'alireza.b1993@gmail.com';

// Sender
$from = $name . ' <' . $email . '>';

//subject and the html message
$subject = 'Message from your website'; 
$message = '
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr><td>Name:</td><td>' . $name . '</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Email:</td><td>' . $email . '</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Message:</td><td>' . nl2br($message) . '</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>';

// Send the mail
$result = sendmail($to, $subject, $message, $from);

//if POST was used, display the message straight away
if ($_POST) {
    if ($result) echo 'Thank you! We have received your message.';
    else echo 'Sorry, unexpected error. Please try again later';

//else if GET was used, return the boolean value so that 
//ajax script can react accordingly
//1 means success, 0 means failed
} else {
    echo $result;   
}

// If the errors array has values
} else {}


// Simple mail function with HTML header
function sendmail($to, $subject, $message, $from) {
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";

$result = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

if ($result) return 1;
else return 0;
}

?>
```

html code :

```
<div id="contact-form">
        <form method="post" action="contact.php" style="direction:rtl">

            <div class="field">
                <label>name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" class="text" />
            </div>

            <div class="field">
                <label>email :<span>*</span></label>
                <input type="text" name="email" class="text" />
            </div>

            <div class="field">
                <label>message :<span>*</span></label>
                <textarea name="message" class="text textarea" ></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="field">
                <input type="button" id="send" value="ارسال"/>
                <div class="loading"></div>
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
```

and this is js code :

```
(function() {
var animateSpeed=300;
var emailReg = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9.-]{2,4}$/;

// Validating

function validateName(name) {
    if (name.val()=='*') {name.addClass('validation-error',animateSpeed); return false;}
    else {name.removeClass('validation-error',animateSpeed); return true;}
}

function validateEmail(email,regex) {
    if (!regex.test(email.val())) {email.addClass('validation-error',animateSpeed); return false;}
    else {email.removeClass('validation-error',animateSpeed); return true;}
}

function validateMessage(message) {
    if (message.val()=='') {message.addClass('validation-error',animateSpeed); return false;}
    else {message.removeClass('validation-error',animateSpeed); return true;}
}

$('#send').click(function() {

    var result=true;

    var name = $('input[name=name]');
    var email = $('input[name=email]');
    var message = $('textarea[name=message]');

    // Validate
    if(!validateName(name)) result=false;
    if(!validateEmail(email,emailReg)) result=false;
    if(!validateMessage(message)) result=false;

    if(result==false) return false;

    // Data
    var data = 'name=' + name.val() + '&email=' + email.val() + '&message='  + encodeURIComponent(message.val());

    // Disable fields
    $('.text').attr('disabled','true');

    // Loading icon
    $('.loading').show();

    // Start jQuery
    $.ajax({

        // PHP file that processes the data and send mail
        url: "contact.php", 

        // GET method is used
        type: "POST",

        // Pass the data            
        data: data,     

        //Do not cache the page
        cache: false,

        // Success
        success: function (html) {              

            if (html==1) {  

                // Loading icon
                $('.loading').fadeOut('slow');  

                //show the success message
                $('.success-message').slideDown('slow');

                // Disable send button
                $('#send').attr('disabled',true);

            }

            else {
                $('.loading').fadeOut('slow')
                alert('Sorry, unexpected error. Please try again later.');              
            }
        }       
    });

    return false;

});

$('input[name=name]').blur(function(){validateName($(this));});
$('input[name=email]').blur(function(){validateEmail($(this),emailReg); });
$('textarea[name=message]').blur(function(){validateMessage($(this)); });

})();
```

if you want to full html page this is download link
[Download Here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/826m1t9j04bte0r/contactform.zip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in your contact.php code. You check if $errors contain data, but if there is no error, your array not exist.

For check, the must is declare your array empty before:

```
$errors = array();
```

Comment: so you mean i must put $errors = array(); before if (!$errors) {

Comment: i do that but same error . it can passed js from this code if (html==1)

Comment: it always says Sorry, unexpected error. Please try again later , this line is in javascript . i really dont know how to fix it . im confused :(

Comment: srry . the php file is always get 0 , im sure its php problem now

Comment: yes is on your php. Your website is local? Have you the mail function activate in your configuration?

Comment: this is my website http://abgostaran.ir/a/contact.html . but the language is persian . yes all thing is activate . i try with other templates and it work fine but this template that is want not working

Comment: for me the error is " Failed to connect to mailserver". please check your php.ini

Comment: so what i must to do ? . i check this with other servers . but the it return 0 . http://sabarayane.com/a/contact.html

Comment: have you add the  $errors = array(); in your source? or you have error on your configuration mail, because in my server no error. please see : http://cipa.ch/contacttest/contact.html

Comment: yes i put that in first line after <?php . i upload the source template with correct modification but get 0 again. http://sabarayane.com/b/contact.html. can you upload your correct file for me ? i upload it then check in my server

Comment: Your $result is 0 because the mail function not work fine.

Comment: check here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889439/how-to-check-if-php-mail-is-enabled

Comment: yes i check that mail function is disable but in direct admin i cant find php.ini to make it enable

Comment: If you are not the owner of your server you cant do this. Contact your FAI

Comment: ok thanks. but in my other server . sabarayane.com the mail function is enable