# sending mail using phpmailer not working

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am trying to send a mail from php using phpmailer with a pdf attachment located on the server. My code is below. I am not sure where I am going wrong. Please help me. Thanks in advance

```php
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');

$bodytext = "Test mail";
$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = 'myid@something.com';
$email->FromName  = 'my name';
$email->Subject   = 'Message Subject';
$email->Body      = $bodytext;
$email->AddAddress( 'something@gmail.com' );

$file_to_attach = 'pdffiles/test.pdf';

$email->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach , 'test.pdf' );

$email->Send();
```

Comment: start your error_reporting using error_reporting(E_ALL) function and edit your question that which specific error you are facing from this code

Comment: i dont get any error. but mail is not getting sent,,,

Comment: Maybe your host doesn't allow emails sending (php mail() function is disabled -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889439/how-to-check-if-php-mail-is-enabled)...

Answer (score 1):

I think when you are send a file you need to to give the system path not the url path Like

```
$bodytext = "Test mail";
$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = 'myid@something.com';
$email->FromName  = 'my name';
$email->Subject   = 'Message Subject';
$email->Body      = $bodytext;
$email->AddAddress( 'something@gmail.com' );

$file_to_attach = SYSTEM_PATH.'pdffiles/test.pdf';

$email->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach , 'test.pdf' );

$email->Send();
```

Comment: This is correct. Refer to [the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki) for more detail.